# Help writing a testclass for controller extention so far i have the following:

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
   public with sharing class attachPDF {
private final Facturatie__c a;
    public attachPDF(ApexPages.StandardController standardPageController) {
        a = (Facturatie__c)standardPageController.getRecord(); //instantiate the Facturatie__c object for the current record  
    }    
    Facturatie__c  currentRecord = [SELECT Id, Accountname__r.Name FROM Facturatie__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

    public PageReference attachPDF() {
        PageReference pdfPage = Page.Factuur2PDF;
        pdfPage.getParameters().put('id',a.id);
        Blob pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContent();

        Attachment attach = new Attachment(parentId = a.Id, Name = 'Factuur ' + '-' + currentRecord.Accountname__r.Name +'-'+ date.today().format() +'.pdf', body = pdfBlob); //create the attachment object
        insert attach;
        PageReference pageWhereWeWantToGo = new ApexPages.StandardController(a).view();
        pageWhereWeWantToGo.setRedirect(true);
        return pageWhereWeWantToGo;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
@isTest(seeAllData=true) 
public class attachPDFTestClass {

static testMethod void testAttachments() { 
    Facturatie__c a = new Facturatie__c(Facturatie__c.Accountname__r.Name='Test');
    insert a; 

    Attachment attach=new Attachment(); 
    attach.Name='Unit Test Attachment'; 
    Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body'); 
    attach.body=bodyBlob; attach.parentId=a.id;
    insert attach;

    List<Attachment> attachments=[select id, name from Attachment where parent.id=:a.id]; 
    System.assertEquals(1, attachments.size()); 

    Test.StartTest();
    FeedItem f = new FeedItem();
        f.ParentId = a.id;
        f.body = 'test';
        insert f;
        FeedComment fc = new FeedComment();
        fc.CommentBody = 'legal test';
        fc.FeedItemId = f.Id;
        insert fc;
        Test.StopTest();
        System.assertEquals ('legal test', fc.commentbody); 
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> Invalid field initializer

Comment: Could you post more info about your error? Which line, which class?

Comment: @isTest(seeAllData=true) <- makes the world sad. Why aren't you creating your test data?

Comment: In the testclass line 5   Facturatie__c a = new Facturatie....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the value of a relationship field like you are doing here:

```
Facturatie__c a = new Facturatie__c(Facturatie__c.Accountname__r.Name='Test');
```

Not to mention the format of

```
Facturatie__c.Accountname__r.Name='Test'
```

Is not valid, no need to include the Object Name as part of the field name.

You should be setting the Id value to the field

```
Facturatie__c a = new Facturatie__c(Accountname__c = [YOURVALIDID]);
```

You will need to create the `AccountName__c` object first obviously.